# Regex match even number of letters

Tags: python, regex

I need to match an expression in Python with regular expressions that only matches even number of letter occurrences. For example:

```
AAA        # no match
AA         # match
fsfaAAasdf # match
sAfA       # match
sdAAewAsA  # match
AeAiA      # no match
```

An even number of As SHOULD match.

Comment: Do you want to match a specific number of a certain letter?  Or any letter, but for each letter you find in a string, it must be there an even number of times?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure I see the pattern in your examples.  Is it the start and end of the word?

Comment: Why is "sAfA" not a match?  There are 2 A's and 2 is an even number.

Comment: Do you want to be sure that there is at least one pair of AAs? In other words should `foo` match or fail to match?

Comment: Your question is impossibly vague. Look at """sdAAewAAs # match""" ... do you mean ONE match ("AAewAA") or TWO matches (each "AA")? You want even numbers of letters, but you try to use "A*" which (obviously?) matches "", "A", "AA", "AAA", etc -- HUH? Note that 0 is an even number.

Comment: And do you mean match in the sense of re.match() or of re.search()?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the question, and removed extra question that confused people...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[^A]*((AA)+[^A]*)*$
```

And if the `A`s don’t need to be consecutive:

```
^[^A]*(A[^A]*A[^A]*)*$
```

Comment: +1 Looks correct - find any number of non-A characters, followed by pairs of AA with other chars in between. However, it would be slightly more efficient if the (AA)* was (AA)+ ^[^A]*((AA)+[^A]*)*$ . If the original poster wants "ab" to not match the regexp will need a + on the end too, i.e ^[^A]*((AA)+[^A]*)+$ to force at least one pair.

Comment: Can the second version be rewritten as ^([^A]*A[^A]*A[^A]*)*$ ?

Comment: @Chachi-inactive Yes, it can. But I wanted to avoid unnecessary backtracking.

Answer (score 4):

Why work so hard coming up with a hard to read pattern? Just search for all occurrences of the pattern and count how many you find.

```
len(re.findall("A", "AbcAbcAbcA")) % 2 == 0
```

That should be instantly understandable by all experienced programmers, whereas a pattern like "(?

Simple is better.

Comment: cause it's faster, more reusable, more compact, cooler. Also it's my question, and i'm not asking about the BEST way of doing it, just how to do it with regex.

Comment: faster? How do you know? More resuable? Debatable. More compact? Not as important as readability. Cooler? Who cares? A few years from now you will likely regret having to revisit some of your "cool" code. 
Now, the last part of your comment I can agree with -- you didn't ask for the best way. For a random person like me it's hard to tell, since most people ultimately want the best solution but just don't know how to ask, so people like me generally try to steer people in what we think is the right direction. Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

This searches for a block with an odd number of A's. If you found one, the string is bad for you:

```
(?<!A)A(AA)*(?!A)
```

If I understand correctly, the Python code should look like:

```
if re.search("(?<!A)A(AA)*(?!A)", "AeAAi"):
   print "fail"
```

Answer (score 2):

`'A*'` means match any number of `A`'s.  Even 0.

Here's how to match a string with an even number of a's, upper or lower:

```
re.compile(r'''
    ^
    [^a]*
    (
        (
            a[^a]*
        ){2}
    # if there must be at least 2 (not just 0), change the
    # '*' on the following line to '+'
    )* 
    $
    ''',re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)
```

You probably are using `a` as an example.  If you want to match a specific character other than `a`, replace `a` with `%s` and then insert

```
[...]
$
'''%( other_char, other_char, other_char )
[...]
```

Comment: 0 is an even number, too.  But I suspect something like "(AA)+" is more like what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Ooops, I just reread the OP's test cases, and he wants non-contiguous letters, too.  Better just to iterate over the string and count.

Comment: Actually, reading this again, it looks like he wants to match a string with doubled As, and no single As anywhere.

Comment: matching 0 A's is, however, a tautology.

Comment: The author of the question originally asked why his `a*` regex was matching a string like `bb`.  And some days matching 0 `a`'s, isn't super obvious :-)

Answer (score 1):

'*' means 0 or more occurences
'AA' should do the trick.

The question is if you want the thing to match 'AAA'. In that case you would have to do something like:

```
r = re.compile('(^|[^A])(AA)+(?!A)',)
r.search(p)
```

That would work for match even (and only even) number of'A'.

Now if you want to match 'if there is any even number of subsequent letters', this would do the trick:

```
re.compile(r'(.)\1')
```

However, this wouldn't exclude the 'odd' occurences. But it is not clear from your question if you really want that.

Update:
This works for you test cases:

```
re.compile('^([^A]*)AA([^A]|AA)*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that `/A*/` matches the empty string.

Secondly, there are some things that you just can't do with regular expressions. This'll be a lot easier if you just walk through the string and count up all occurences of the letter you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, easier and faster. But Regexps are too fun.

Answer (score 0):

A* means match "A" zero or more times.

For an even number of "A", try: (AA)+

Comment: This will only match strings containing a pair but also a non-pair, i.e AlalaAA will match

Answer (score 0):

It's **impossible** to count **arbitrarily** using regular expressions.  For example, making sure that you have matching parenthesis. To count you need 'memory' which requires something at least as strong as a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), although in this case you can use the regular expression that @Gumbo provided.

The suggestion to use `finditer`is the best workaround for the general case.

Comment: However the question does not require matching. It is not like he is asking to have as many As as Bs or a similar counting problem.