# How to split string into arguments and options in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the array of arguments so I can use it with [optparse-js library](https://github.com/jfd/optparse-js) so If I have something like

```
-f foo -b -a -z baz bar
```

I want array like this

```
["-f", "foo", "-b", "-a", "-z", "baz", "bar"]
```

it should work with strings that have escape quote inside and long GNU options. So far I have regex that match the string

```
/("(?:\\"|[^"])*"|'(?:\\'|[^'])*')/g
```

it match strings like `"das"` or `"asd\"asd"` or `'asd'` or `'sad\'asd'`

Can I use regex for this or do I need a parser (like using PEG) it would be nice if it match regex to so I can do

```
-p "hello b\"ar baz" -f /^ [^ ]+ $/
```

**UPDATE**: with help from @Damask I've created this regex:

```
/('(\\'|[^'])*'|"(\\"|[^"])*"|\/(\\\/|[^\/])*\/|(\\ |[^ ])+|[\w-]+)/g
```

it work for strings like this:

```
echo -p "hello b\"ar baz" -f /^ [^ ]+ $/
```

it return

```
['echo', '-p', '"hello b\"ar baz"', '-f', '/^ [^ ]+ $/']
```

but if fail on strings like this:

```
echo "&copy;\\\\" abc "baz"
```

it match command and two arguments instead of 3 arguments [demo](https://regex101.com/r/megSzL/1)

if argument don't have spaces like "foo"baz it should be one item in array, quotes need to be included but I will remove not escaped ones from string (like in bash when you execute `echo "foo"bar` echo will get one foobar argument).

Comment: To get from the first string to the array mentioned, you can use split(" ") but I assume you need to elaborate on the first 2 sentences (￣(エ)￣)

Comment: @mplungjan I need solution that will work with something like `-p "hello b\"ar baz" -f /^ [^ ]+ $/`

Comment: So I suggest you swap your examples and show how the array would look with a real example

Comment: is the input is   "-f foo -b -a -z baz bar " is string or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some comments:

- The raw regex for quotes is this
  `"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'`
  Example: http://regex101.com/r/uxqApc/2
- This part `(?= :? | $ )` will always resolve to true, and is useless
- This part `/(\\/|[^/])+/[gimy]*` if this is a regex (or any delimited item)
  you have to blindly handle escape anything. Like this `/[^/\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^/\\]*)*/[gimy]*`.
  Otherwise it would match `/..\\//` which is not correct.
- This expression `(?: \\ \s | \S )+` is first in the alternation sequence,   i.e. before this one `[\w-]+`. Since not whitespace `\S` is a superset of `[\w-]`, it means this `[\w-]+` never, ever get's reached.

Making the corrections and putting it all back together gets this regex:
`/("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|\/[^\/\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^\/\\]*)*\/[gimy]*(?=\s|$)|(?:\\\s|\S)+)/`

Demo's:

JavaScript - http://regex101.com/r/cuJuQ8/1
PCRE - http://regex101.com/r/cuJuQ8/2

[Formatted](http://regexformat.com)

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      "
      [^"\\]* 
      (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
      "
   |  
      ' 
      [^'\\]* 
      (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
      '
   |  
      / 
      [^/\\]* 
      (?: \\ [\S\s] [^/\\]* )*
      /
      [gimy]* 
      (?= \s | $ )
   |  
      (?: \\ \s | \S )+
 )                             # (1 end)
```

---

---

*If also, you need to parse this like the space (outside of quotes or regex) is a delimiter as well, this would be it:*

`/((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|\/[^\/\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^\/\\]*)*\/[gimy]*(?=\s|$)|(?:\\\s|\S))+)(?=\s|$)/`

Demo's:

JavaScript -  http://regex101.com/r/cuJuQ8/3
PCRE - https://regex101.com/r/cuJuQ8/4

Formatted

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           "
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
           "
        |  
           ' 
           [^'\\]* 
           (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
           '
        |  
           / 
           [^/\\]* 
           (?: \\ [\S\s] [^/\\]* )*
           /
           [gimy]* 
           (?= \s | $ )
        |  
           (?: \\ \s | \S )
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?= \s | $ )
```

Answer (score 5):

I really love regex but sometimes a combination of simple regex and simple function does the same job but is a lot easier to debug and maintain, especially when developers not familiar with *(complex)* regex join the project.

So here is another approach, see explanation below.

It's tested using this rather complicated sample with arguments containing many spaces or escaped double quotes as required :

> `echo "&copy;\\\\" abc "baz" "foo bar  dummy" -d "marty \\\"mc fly" -f "avb eer\"" -p 2 "asd\"asd" -a 3`

**Code Snippet**

```js
function commandArgs2Array(text) {
  const re = /^"[^"]*"$/; // Check if argument is surrounded with double-quotes
  const re2 = /^([^"]|[^"].*?[^"])$/; // Check if argument is NOT surrounded with double-quotes

  let arr = [];
  let argPart = null;

  text && text.split(" ").forEach(function(arg) {
    if ((re.test(arg) || re2.test(arg)) && !argPart) {
      arr.push(arg);
    } else {
      argPart = argPart ? argPart + " " + arg : arg;
      // If part is complete (ends with a double quote), we can add it to the array
      if (/"$/.test(argPart)) {
        arr.push(argPart);
        argPart = null;
      }
    }
  });

  return arr;
}

let result = commandArgs2Array('echo "&copy;\\\\" abc "baz" "foo bar  dummy" -d "marty \\\"mc fly" -f "avb eer\"" -p 2 "asd\"asd" -a 3');
console.log(result);
```

**Explanation**

First, arguments are splitted using space char.

For each argument, we check if it's a *complete* or an *incomplete* argument

> A *complete* argument is an argument which is either
>
> - surrounded with double-quotes
> - NOT surrounded with double-quotes at all
>
> Every other case represents an *incomplete* argument. It's​ either
>
> - The start of an incomplete argument (starts with a double-quote)
> - A space
> - A part of an incomplete argument which can contain escaped double-quotes
> - The end of an incomplete argument (ends with a double-quote)

That's all folks !

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Syntax error",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 40
}

Comment: This is because you're using a browser which does not support ES2015. I've edited answer to fix it. Thanx for pointing it.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you simply use split function?

```
var arr = myString.split(/\s+/);
```

you better pass a regexp as argument to avoid bugs in cases when separator is `\t` or there are multiple spaces etc.

**EDIT:**

if your arguments have spaces and are in quote marks, I think you can't find a single regexp. Think you should find arguments with spaces at first (`/"(.*?)"/` in group 1 you'll get argument), add them to array, then remove them from string and only after that use split method like described above.

Comment: I suggested that too. But that seems to be too simple to put in an answer

Comment: I can't use just that because I can have strings or regexes that have spaces as argument to an options

Comment: IIRC, there is a solution to tokenize string that is inside quote `"`, but it requires feature not available in JS Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = '-f foo "ds  df s\\" da" -b -a -z baz bar';
a.match(/([\w-]+|"(\\"|[^"])*")/g)
```

returns `[ "-f", "foo", ""ds  df s\" da"", "-b", "-a", "-z", "baz", "bar"]`

Comment: with your help I created better regex `/('(\\'|[^'])*'|"(\\"|[^"])*"|\/(\\\/|[^\/])*\/|(\\ |[^ ])+|[\w-]+)/g` that match regex, single quote, and text with escape space.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var input = '-p "hello b\"ar baz" -f /^ [^ ]+ $/ -c -d -e'
var arr = input.split(' -');
var out = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(~arr[i].indexOf(' ')){
        out = out.concat([arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].indexOf(' ')), arr[i].substring(arr[i].indexOf(' ')+1)])
    }else{
        out = out.concat('-'+arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
["-p", ""hello b"ar baz"", "f", "/^ [^ ]+ $/", "-c", "-d", "-e"]
```

I know it's not a fancy 1-line regex, but it works like expected.

Comment: it don't work with escaped quotes `var input = 'echo "asd\\"asd" asd'` in your case escape `\"` should be `\\"` to have slash in input and not quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var string = "-f foo -b -a -z baz bar";
        string = string.split(" ");
    var stringArray = new Array();
    for(var i =0; i < string.length; i++){
        stringArray.push(string[i]);
    }
    console.log(stringArray);
```

output will be console like this

Array [ "-f", "foo", "-b", "-a", "-z", "baz", "bar" ]

Comment: This will not work for 'echo "foo bar" baz` and you don't need to iterate over array, string will already be an array, so `stringArray` and `string` is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, even that I created a Bounty for this question I found the answer with help from [Regex match even number of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045175/regex-match-even-number-of-letters#2045208)

and my regex look like this:

```
/('((?:[^\\]*(?:\\\\)*\\')+|[^']*)*'|"(?:(?:[^\\]*(?:\\\\)*\\")+|[^"]*)*"|(?:\/(\\\/|[^\/])+\/[gimy]*)(?=:? |$)|(\\\s|\S)+|[\w-]+)/
```

[with demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxqApc/1)

**EDIT**: @sin suggesion make better regex:

```
/("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?:\/(\\\/|[^\/])+\/[gimy]*)(?=:? |$)|(\\\s|\S)+|[\w-]+)/
```

Comment: This one is wrong too, it fails because you didn't take account that characters other than quotes or slashes may also be escaped, example: `"ab\cd"`. You don't also need to know if the number of backslashes is odd or even. To finish, using `[^\\]*` *(at the beginning)* allows to go out of the quoted part and to reach an eventual other quoted part: `'abc' -p 'def\'ghi'`. A simple way to match quoted parts with escaped quotes is: `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` *(replace the dot with `[\s\S]` or `[^]` if you also want to match escaped newlines)*

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you added `(?=:? |$)` after the pattern part?

Comment: The raw regex for quotes is this `"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'` (https://regex101.com/r/uxqApc/2) what the heck are you trying to do ??

Comment: @sin Oh, thanks, that's much better string matching regex I added it to my command line split regex, that also need to match normal words, numbers and regexes.

Comment: I'm not sure what the other parts of your regex is supposed to do but this part `(?= :? | $ )` will always resolve to _`true`_, and is useless.

Comment: As for this part `/(\\/|[^/])+/[gimy]*`. If this is a regex (or any delimited item) you have to blindly handle escape anything. Like this `/[^/\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^/\\]*)*/[gimy]*`. Otherwise it would match `/..\\//` which is not correct.

Comment: Also, this expression `(?: \\ \s | \S )+` is first in the alternation sequence, i.e. before this one `[\w-]+`. Since not whitespace `\S` is a superset of `[\w-]`, it means this `[\w-]+` never, ever get's reached.

Comment: Putting it all together, its this `/("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|\/[^\/\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^\/\\]*)*\/[gimy]*(?=\s|$)|(?:\\\s|\S)+)/` and the demo https://regex101.com/r/cuJuQ8/1 or this https://regex101.com/r/cuJuQ8/2

Comment: @sin you can add this as an answer.

Comment: @jcubic  added it.