# Regex Binary String Contains at Least, Ends With and even number of 0's

Tags: regex, binary

The question concerns writing regular expressions for binary strings.

How do you write one such that it 
starts with 1, has at-least two zeros and has even number of zero's

Comment: Your title says even number of 1s but text says even number of 0s. Or both?

Comment: updated: its only zero's. And the string could be of any length

Comment: You need to clarify your question and specifications.

Comment: Binary string length can be maximum upto 1000 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^1+(1*01*01*)+$
```

Three rules:

- Starts with `1`
- Has even number of `0`'s
- Contains at least 2 `0`'s

Details:

- `^1+` ensures atleast one `1` at the start
- `(1*01*01*)+` matches a group with two `0`'s at a time which have any number of `1`'s in between. The `+` ensures that *at least* one such group is matched, which implies that a minimum of two `0`'s be present in the match

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4BQg4f/4)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

> How do you write one such that it starts with 1, has at-least two zeros and has even number of zero's

This would do it: `\b1(?:00)+\b`

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYXYT8/3)

**Edit1:** 
If strings such as `10000111` is supposed to be accepted (as commented by OP on this answer), then this regex would be necessary: `\b1(?:00)+1*\b`

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYXYT8/4)

**Edit2:** 
After being presented with even more restraits in comments from OP on this post.

> It should even number of zero's at any point with at-least two zeros minimum and first character should be 1

Regex: `\b1(?:00|1)+\b`

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYXYT8/6)

Comment: @Shoaib627 ofc it doesn't... there were no mention of there being anything behind the `even number of zero's`.

Comment: any thing can be present after the zeros. can u please modify accordingly. by anything i meant 0 or 1

Comment: @Shoaib627 if anything can proceed the zeros  then there's no way of knowing if there's an even number of zeros.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses: Now this fails: 1000011100. It still has even number of zeros

Comment: Can this be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045175/regex-match-even-number-of-letters

Comment: @Shoaib627 your use case wont ever work.  You need to rephrase your question and rethink how you explain your intended functionality.

Comment: its just that even number of zeros, with at least two zeros and should start with 1

Comment: @Shoaib627 no its obviously not. You just told me that there can be any number of 1's OR 0's after the "even number of 0's".

Comment: sorry my bad. it should even number of zero's at any point with at-least  two zeros minimum and  first character should be 1