# Regex Match a non-empty sequence of characters, where there is even amount of a given character (including 0) and any amount of the other characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a non-empty sequence of A's and B's, where the A's are even which includes 0.

For example:

```
AABBABA -> AABBABA
BBBB -> BBBB
A -> nothing
```

Here is what I could come up with so far:

```
(AA+B*|B*AB*A|B*)+
```

But currently it is of course only gonna match what's in the parentheses not just any pattern of A's and B's. **I am having trouble generalizing getting even amount of A's.**

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to use regex for this. What programming language (if any) are you using?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed unfortunately it is a purely regex exercise. Otherwise I would know to do hopefully lol

Comment: Start here maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045175/regex-match-even-number-of-letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use regex, you may use something like this:

```
^(?:B*(?:AB*A)*B*)*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1QNKxL/2)**.

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way but it seems to do the job.

This will basically match Two `A` characters with zero or more `B` characters in between and the whole thing is repeated zero or more times. This guarantees that the `A` count will be even. Then we have zero or more `B` characters at the beginning and end in case the string starts with or ends with `B`. And then the whole thing is repeated zero or more times again.

If you want to reject empty strings (and assuming your regex flavor supports Lookaheads), you can add a simple Lookahead that looks for one character to the beginning of the pattern:

```
^(?=.)(?:B*(?:AB*A)*B*)*$
```

Comment: It does not work with AABAA or something similar where A's are after.

Comment: @Alec Updated. Check now.

Comment: Looks like its working from what I can see, thank you Regex is a pain!

Comment: @Alec Regex isn't a pain when used for the right task. This task can be accomplished very easily by counting the number of `A` and `B` characters in the string. Something that can be done very easily (and more efficiently) using almost any programming language. I wouldn't use regex for this as mentioned in the comment on the question above.

Comment: Agreed with the comment about using an actual programming langue to solve it. It would have been much easier.

Comment: I think nesting the quantifiers like that might cause catastrophic backtracking https://regex101.com/r/h6wKwY/1

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to match an empty string without lookarounds, you might also use

```
^(?:(?:B*AB*A)+B*|B+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?:B*AB*A)+B*` Match 1+ times pairs of A's between optional B's
  - `|` Or
  - `B+` Match 1+ occurrences of B
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ByK0d/1)